# When we upload the build on iTunes we have facing that Build on iTunes always show processing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image]when i upload my binary build from my xcode it is succesed but not show on itunes build

When we upload the build on iTunes we have facing that Build on iTunes always show processing Please resolve my issue. I can't release my build after long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload your app with Application loader. Using Xcode we face this issue often.

Comment: We have added new binary from Application loader. we have not get the solution please help...

Comment: Wait for 30 minutes. It sometime take 30 or more minutes to complete processing. What is the size of your IPA?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your apple id from xcode and relogin again.